# Apache .htaccess, url rewriting issue

Tags: apache, .htaccess, https, fastcgi

I hosted my python flask web app to fluxflex cloud hosting (Apache, FastCGI). So, .htaccess file looks like the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /dispatch.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

It works. Now I want to redirect from http to https. How can I do that? Added the following 
two lines at the end of .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

but, got response: Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS). If I insert this two lines before the first rewrite, response is: Page Not Found.

Can someone show me proper way of redirecting to https?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the `%{HTTPS}` variable:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

add a rule to redirect to https before the fcgi call
This redirect must only occur if http is requested:

My .htaccess looks like that:

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
        AddHandler cgi-script .fcgi
        RewriteEngine On

        #redirect to https if http, notice the L tag
        #it will break the rule processing and trigger the redirection        
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://${HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,QSA,L]

        #handle the request (must be https at this point)
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dispatch.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```